Flutter - Using Flavors for optional SDKs
I plan to create two versions of my Flutter-App for different localities - one for the US and one for the EU. Now, I want to use the Meta-SDK for tracking ads, but am only allowed to keep this inside the US-version, for regulatory reasons. The app is being compiled to Android and iOS
Is it possible to use Flutter flavors to have one EU-version without the installed SDK and one US-version with the installed SDK?
